# Why is my printf output crooked?

Tags: c, debugging, printf

I want all my lines to line up correctly, but for some reason when i print it out it looks crooked, like this:

```
Weather summary for 2013

|   Month   | High  |  Low  |  Avg  | Precip  |
|-----------|-------|-------|-------|---------|
|    January| 9.8   | -26.2  | -7.8  | 55.3  |
|   February| 7.5   | -23.3  | -8.6  | 33.1  |
|      March| 14.2  | -19.6  | -4.7  | 33.2  |
|      April| 23.7  | -5.3  | 6.2   | 56.8  |
|        May| 33.0  | -0.6  | 13.9  | 62.7  |
|       June| 32.1  | 8.0   | 19.7  | 69.7  |
|       July| 34.9  | 12.6  | 22.2  | 181.8  |
|     August| 31.5  | 11.0  | 20.9  | 69.2  |
|  September| 34.1  | 5.0   | 16.1  | 69.0  |
|    October| 24.8  | -2.9  | 10.8  | 56.9  |
|   November| 16.0  | -12.8  | 2.1   | 36.2  |
|   December| 15.6  | -17.8  | -4.2  | 65.8  |
```

my code for the printf call:

```
printf("| %10s| %-4.1f  | %-4.1f  | %-4.1f  | %-4.1f    |\n",month_names[month - 1] ,
monthly->maxTemperature,monthly->minTemperature, monthly->averageTemperature, monthly->totalPrecipitation);
```

Thanks!

Comment: `4.1` --> `5.1` The `5` if for the minimum character width as in `-12.8`

Comment: ok that worked, i forgot to count the proper amount of chars i guess.

Comment: Also, how would you get the digits to align properly? for every digit to line up to the right

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of formatted output, all you need is a rough estimation of the width of each field, then let `printf` do all the formatting, instead of counting the spaces then coming up with something like `%4.1f`..

For example in this case, start with the header, give a rough estimate of the width of each header fields:
`printf( "|%-20s|%-10s|%-10s|%-10s|%-10s|\n", "Month", "High", "Low", "Avg", "Precip" );`

Then for the following rows, use the same width, just replace `%s` with `%f` for float numbers. You can manipulate how many position after the decimal point.

`printf( "|%-20s|%-10.1f|%-10.1f|%-10.1f|%-10.1f|\n", ...`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using -4.1f as your printf specifier, you will always get 1 space after the decimal point, so 4 total spaces isn't enough for the negative numbers, and printf is adding an extra space in the output for you.  So, you will need to use -5.1f to get enough space for one decimal point and the - sign.  So, if you end up with a number like -123.4, you won't get proper alignment again.